Transient DBCC Checkdb error
We run DBCC checkdb against our alwayson secondary replica and primary replica on version 2016 SP3.
It normally completes without error. However, on 2 occasions in the last 4 months, the secondary replica has reported a corruption:
The operating system returned error 1392(The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.) to SQL Server during a write at offset 0x00000d0a690000 in file ‘E:\xxx\data\xxx.ndf_MSSQL_DBCC9’. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
Subsequent executions of checkdb report no corruption. I have logged an incident with MS a few months ago, and and they told me to run chkdsk, which came back with zero errors, then told me it was likely a transient write error and likely safe to ignore. I’m not 100% comfortable ignoring this, but I am coming close to being out of ideas on how to troubleshoot it.
So far I have checked the following:

Windows system and Event log on both nodes.
Cluster log on both nodes.
SQL Server error log.

So far no obvious clues. So just wondering how others in my position might proceed from here? Many thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Just my thoughts, if MS has told you to ignore it, and, dbcc checkdb comes back clean on all of the databases, I would probably not give it any future thought.  It could truly be a transient write error which is safe to ignore.  The only thing I can think of to check possibly would ask your storage team to check the health and any errors from the storage side of the disks due to it being a write error that only occurs at certain times.

thanks for your advice
